# codeigniter session config file

Tags: codeigniter, session

there are 2 values in the config file for codeigniter session which i do not fully understand and hope someone can enlighten me, thanks.

```
# the number of SECONDS you want the session to last.
# by default sessions last 7200 seconds (two hours).
# Set to zero for no expiration.
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
```

Q1) Will the application logout the user when the time(2 hrs after login) is up even though the user is still actively using the application?

```
# how many seconds between CI refreshing Session Information
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
```

Q2) Does this value affect the (Q1) senario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$config['sess_expiration']` is how long it will take before the session expires if there is no activity by the user on the session. `$config['sess_time_to_update']` will update the expiration time every 5 minutes while the user is actively using the session.

So if the user logs in, has an expiration of 2 hours, and navigates around the site for 30 minutes and then leaves the site, they will have 2 hours from that point to visit again without needing to log in. If they do visit in those 2 hours, the expiration time will be reset to 2 hours from that point. If they don't visit again, they'll need to login.

Therefor if they are using the session they will not be logged out after 2 hours.

Comment: hi mark, i set the $config['sess_expiration'] = 60;. i was logout after 60 sec even though i'm still actively using it. What had happen?

Comment: i set sess_time_to_update = 120. i'm using session database also.

Comment: The sess_time_to_update has to be lower the the sess_expiration if you don't want to be logged out after the time in sess_expiration.